# How do I count in Myst?

Tags: myst-series

So, I'm currently playing Myst V: End of Ages, and I've found quite a few D'ni numbers around. I know I've seen them in Riven, but I can't find my notes from then, and can't find a way to translate them here.

Anyway, can someone tell me how the number system works in the Myst universe?

Comment: FWIW, it's entirely possible to decode them from Riven alone. Riven is the *fifth* age, and various other numerical patterns make it a fairly straightforward deduction. In fact, I think one of the puzzles is directly dependent on you solving at least the first few numbers, though I may be misremembering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a base 25 numbering system that is broken up into 5 groups of 5 symbols.  Once you know the symbols for 0 - 4, the symbols for 5 - 9, 10 - 14, 15 - 19, and 20 - 24 are the same, but they will have a modifier for 5, 10, etc. added to them.  14 is the symbol for 4 and the symbol for 10 superimposed.

[Here](http://dni.wikia.com/wiki/D%27ni_Numerals) is a more comprehensive article on it, with pictures for the numbers.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks. I finally found my notes, and I only had them up to ten, so this is still very useful.